# SlectedItem when I click in a textbox or button in Datatemplate of a listview

Tags: c#, listview, win-universal-app

I have a textbox and a button in a datatemplate as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemp1" x:DataType="data:Test">
                <StackPanel Width="400">
                    <TextBox x:Name="tBoxName" Text="{Binding PhoneNumebr, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="textbutton"  Click="myButtonButton_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and here my listView:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemp1}"
                      SelectionChanged="myList_SelectionChanged" 
                      IsItemClickEnabled="False"/>
```

for a listView in an UWP app, so I need a solution, that when I select the textbox or button, then selecteditem is accrued. In fact selectionchanged event is not fired when textbox or button is selected. is there any way to get selected item when textbox or button is selected? thanks

Comment: Could you please try to get some readability into your text?

Comment: Post complete listview xaml

Comment: Make IsItemClickEnabled=true.

Comment: It is not related to isItemClick, I want to select item when I click in textBox or button

Comment: If IsItemClickEnabled=false, how will you click TextBox?

Comment: If you dont want to make to true then you have to make it selected  programmatically

Comment: IsItemclick is used when you select a item in listView not selecting a textbox or any elemant in datatemplate.In fact, by selecting a button or textBox item is not selected and selectionchanged is not accured. item just is highlighted.

Comment: Yes. selectionchanged  is not triggered because you dint click the item(because its disabled),you clicked textbox or button. That what i said.

Comment: @Shahramfr does it solve the problem? Or do you have any doubts?

Comment: as I have already explained, your solution is not related to thing which I needed. I found out a solution in this link but unfortuantelly it is not working. this link :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a5191023-fcdd-4e94-924e-6dee8e888267/uwp-xaml-button-on-list-item?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved as MikeBMcL explaind at this ilink:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a5191023-fcdd-4e94-924e-6dee8e888267/uwp-xaml-button-on-list-item?forum=wpdevelop